# How to string format a float to the 10s or 100s place?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, format

How do I string format, either `%` or `.format()`, a float to round and display to the 10s or 100s place?

Like 4552.33 to 4550 to 10s place or 4600 to 100s?

Comment: Can anyone dupe hammer this question with the link @roganjosh mentioned

Comment: @stephen all you need is `round(4552.33, -2)` and `round(4552.33, -1)`

Comment: https://pyformat.info/#number_padding

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in function [`round`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round),

```
>>> import math
>>> f = 4552.33
>>> int(round(f, -int(math.log10(10))))
4550
>>> int(round(f, -int(math.log10(100))))
4600
```